# Can iEqualityComparer be used to keep one object over another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I am using linq-to-entities to populate a list of objects, I am then using .Distinct(new objectComparer()) to get distinct records. I want to ensure that certain objects are retained in the list over other objects.

Object:

```
public class Student
{
    public int NSN { get; set; }
    //removed properties not relevant
    public int EnrolmentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comparer:

```
public class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        //Check whether the properties are equal. 
        return x.NSN == y.NSN;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        return obj.NSN.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var students = (from t1 in Entities.Table1
                join t2 in Entities.Table2
                on t1.someID equals t2.someID
                where (new int?[] { 3, 6, 10 }).Contains(t2.EnrolmentStatus)
                select new Student
                {
                    NSN = t1.NSN,
                    EnrolmentStatus = t2.EnrolmentStatus
                }).ToList().Distinct(new StudentComparer());
```

This code returns distinct NSN values, however I would like to ensure that objects with EnrolmentStatus of 3 or 6 are preferred over EnrolmentStatus 10. Is there any way to do this with an iEqualityComparer or should I use a different approach?

Comment: You can't do that with equality comparer (and I don't actually think you can get custom comparer to be used in linq-to-entities, I believe it will run as regular linq-to-objects). You can group items first and that pick one that you like the mos from each group (that you may be able to even do SQL side if not using custom comparer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe you are correct about linq-to-objects which is why I have to ToList the results before using Distinct. Can you provide an example of using grouping to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

```
.DistinctBy(x => Student.NSN)
```

Comment: First thanks for the reply, but from the documentation on the website provided: 'This operator uses deferred execution and streams the results, although a set of already-seen keys is retained. If a key is seen multiple times, only the **first element** with that key is returned.' The important point is bolded, I would like to choose which element is kept.